# Given an integer N, in how many ways can we tile a 4 x N rectangle with 3 x 1 tiles?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I know tiling problems are not uncommon and they are usually solved with Dynamic programming. I've also read quite similar question [here](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/UVa_10918) about tiling 3XN rectangle with 2X1 tiles but I still have problem figuring out the recurrent relations.

Right now I know you can title 4X3 rectangle with 3X1 titles in 3 ways. So there's a relation here like f(n) = 3*f(n-3) + [other]. I've been scratching my head for a while now to figure what the 'other' part should be. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show how you would tile that 4X3 rectangle with 3X1 tiles in 3 ways?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I can answer that |||| E| |E, consider E as three parallel tiles

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes as Boris said. I fell asleep after posting :(

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you can get a closed form solution to this easily, instead you can do a bit mask DP that takes the state of the last 4x3 block with the first column unfulfilled.

The reason you can't get a closed form sol is because of tilings like these

```
 ======
 ||===|
 ||===|
 ||===|
```

And depending on the next tile you place your bitmask will change and you will be able to get some sort of recursive algorithm. You can read more about bitmask DPs here

http://www.quora.com/Algorithms/How-can-we-cover-an-MxN-area-with-minimum-cost-from-a-set-of-tiles-having-different-dimensions-and-different-cost

Comment: Thanks! But I think there's better reference than that Quora question about bitmask DP :)

Answer (score 2):

Following the link you've posted, I've tried to reconstruct the recursive relation so it will fit 4XN rectangles and 3X1 tiles, this is what i've got:

```
********   AAA*******   BBB******   A*******
******** = BBB******* + A******** + A*******
********   CCC*******   A********   A*******
********   DDD*******   A********   BBB*****
  f(n)   =  f(n-3)    +  g(n-1)  +  g(n-1)

********   AB*******   AAA******   ABBB******
********   AB*******   BBB******   ACCC******
******** = AB******* + CCC****** + ADDD******
  ******     *******     *******     ********
  g(n)   =   f(n-2)  +   h(n-2)  +   i(n-2)

********   AAA******   
 *******    ********   
 ******* =  ******** 
 *******    ********  
  h(n)   =   g(n-1)  

********   AAA******   
  ******     *******   
  ****** =   *******
  ******     *******  
  i(n)   =   j(n-2) 

  ******     *******    ********   
 *******    A*******   AAA******
 ******* =  A******* + BBB******
 *******    A*******   CCC******
  j(n)   =   f(n-1)      i(n-1)
```

From that we get:

```
f(n) = f(n-3) + 2*g(n-1)
g(n) = f(n-2) + h(n-2) + i(n-2)   ==>   g(n) = f(n-2) + g(n-3) + i(n-2)
h(n) = g(n-1)
i(n) = j(n-2)
j(n) = f(n-1) + i(n-1)
```

And the stopping conditions for the functions are:

```
f(0) = 1, f(1) = 0, f(2) = 0
g(0) = 0, g(1) = 1, g(2) = 1
i(0) = 0, i(1) = 0 
j(0) = 0
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It should be possible to solve the equation f(n) = f(n - 3) + 2 g(n - 1) for g(n - 1) and then substitute into the equation g(n) = f(n - 2) + g(n - 3) to get one recurrence, for f. Unfortunately, it seems that you missed a case -- from a g configuration, lay a vertical to the left of three horizontals in the upper lefthand corner. (Also, the stopping condition for g(1) should be 0.)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Agreed on the missing case (I added it to the answer), about `g(1) = 0`, `g(1)` is just 3 vertical spaces, so a single tile can cover it. I think `g(1)` never happens in this recursive relation anyway.

Comment: Not when 3 divides the initial value of n, no.

Comment: f(n) = f(n-3) + 2*g(n-1); g(n)=f(n-2)+g(n-3)+h(n-4); h(n)=h(n-3)+f(n-1); I think it will work fine and is less complicated. Also, what logic did you use to get stopping condition?

Answer (score 1):

To prove that a recurrence is correct, you need to work out the cases as Ron did, but if you just want to know what it is experimentally, then a couple of terms (depending on the degree of the recurrence) may suffice. The first few are 1, 3, 13, 57, 249, 1087, 4745. Then you can solve for the coefficients with linear algebra.

```
[ 1  3  13] [x]   [  57]
[ 3 13  57] [y] = [ 249]
[13 57 249] [z]   [1087]
```

The solution is x = 1 and y = -3 and z = 5. We can now verify that 57 - 3*249 + 5*1087 = 4745, and [OEIS confirms](https://oeis.org/A049086) (another great resource) that the recurrence indeed is T(N) = 5 T(N - 1) - 3 T(N - 2) + T(N - 3). Here's the Python code I used.

```
import numpy
memo = {frozenset(): 1}

def memoized_ntilings(s, k=3):
    if (s in memo):
        return memo[s]
    (x, y) = min(s)
    n = 0
    h = frozenset((((x + i), y) for i in range(k)))
    if h.issubset(s):
        n += memoized_ntilings((s - h), k)
    v = frozenset(((x, (y + i)) for i in range(k)))
    if v.issubset(s):
        n += memoized_ntilings((s - v), k)
    memo[s] = n
    return n

def ntilings(n, m=4):
    return memoized_ntilings(frozenset(((x, y) for x in range(n) for y in range(m))))

def fibonacci(n):
    (a, b) = (0, 1)
    for i in range(n):
        (a, b) = (b, (a + b))
    return a

def guess_recurrence(callable):
    degree = 1
    while True:
        ab = numpy.array([[callable((i + j)) for i in range((degree + 2))] for j in range((degree + 5))])
        a = ab[:, :(- 1)]
        b = ab[:, (- 1)]
        result = numpy.linalg.lstsq(a, b)
        x = result[0]
        residuals = result[1]
        if (numpy.linalg.norm(residuals) < (1e-12 * numpy.linalg.norm(b))):
            return x
        degree += 1
if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    print(guess_recurrence(fibonacci))
    print(guess_recurrence((lambda n: ntilings((n * 3)))))
```

The output is the following.

```
[ 1.  1.]
[ 1. -3.  5.]
```